# SQL Developer: invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle, case

This is the part of my query that has error:

```
, case  when dsi.distributor_id in 
('ALBQA','ASGLA','ASGNY','ASGR1','ASGSF','BIKU9','COAUU','CSWHP','DPIB1','DPID9',
'DPISP','DPISQ','EAS3X','GEP79','GRG8V','NACY7','NOSYK','ORGK7','PETR1','TOP0U',
    'UNFIA','UNFIL','UNFIQ','UNFIS','UNMQ9','KOSI8','KEHEN','CSNYC','ALBQA','ALC6Y','BAM7D','BIKU9','CLCE0','COAUU','CSWHT','EAS3X','FOUXU','GEP79',
'GRG8V','HED9Q','LAOJD','MCLFS','NOSYK','ORGK7','UNMQ9','OMAH1'
)
      then 'Distributor'
      else 'Direct'
      end as is_direct
, SUM(dsi.cost) AS tot_cost

, SUM(CASE WHEN is_direct = 'Direct' THEN dsi.cost ELSE 0 END ) AS Direct_cost
```

It says that `is_direct` is an invalid column but I already indicated it above. Therefore, I was wondering if you could help me find where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Columns defined in your query cannot be used in other places in your query, whether it is in other columns, or `WHERE` clauses, etc.

I would suggest either placing these calculations into subqueries, or using `WITH AS`.